# How to solve a rendering issue with facebook loginbutton?

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I am trying to implement facebook into my app.  I was following the directions from the facebook developers site, but got stuck on a step which wasn't explained fully, or in my case, assumed I knew what they were talking about.

Either way, I added the facebook sdk, and did all the preliminary steps as required.  However when I add the facebook loginbutton to my gameconsole.xml and try to switch it to design view in android studio I get a rendering error.

Here's my gameconsole.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

         <RelativeLayout
           xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
           xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
           android:layout_width="match_parent"
           android:layout_height="match_parent"
           android:orientation="vertical" 
           android:id="@+id/gameconsole_bg">


   <ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
    android:maxHeight="325dp"
    android:adjustViewBounds="true"

    />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/editText1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/imageView1"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
    android:capitalize="characters"
    android:ems="10"
    android:gravity="center" />


<TextView
    android:id="@+id/editText2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/imageButton2"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="97dp"
    android:ems="5"
    android:visibility="invisible"
    />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/editText3"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/editText2"
    android:layout_below="@+id/imageButton2"
    android:ems="5"
    android:visibility="invisible"
     />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/imageView1"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:text="@string/pc1"
    android:textSize="12sp"
    android:textColor="#ffffff" />


<ImageButton
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@drawable/help"
    android:id="@+id/imageButton3"
    android:layout_above="@+id/editText2"
    android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/editText3"
    android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/editText3" />

<ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/imageButton2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@drawable/rateus"
    android:layout_marginTop="60dp"
    android:layout_below="@+id/editText1"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/editText3"
    android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/editText3" />



    <com.facebook.login.widget.LoginButton
        android:id="@+id/login_button"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="30dp" />





    </RelativeLayout>
```

I've read somewhere that facebook.sdkinitialize must be called first for the UI to work?  Ok fine.  I put this line of code in my application code

```
 import android.app.Application;
 import com.facebook.FacebookSdk;
 import com.facebook.appevents.AppEventsLogger;

public class MyApp extends Application {

@Override
public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();
    // Initialize the SDK before executing any other operations,
    FacebookSdk.sdkInitialize(getApplicationContext());
    AppEventsLogger.activateApp(this);
```

My real question is what does this matter anyway?  I'm not running the program so nothing is being initialized yet.  I'm just trying to add the button in design mode BEFORE the program is run.  In design mode, no program is being run, or am I wrong?  I'm still new to programming and this is giving me a headache.  Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Rendering problems are usually related to your dependencies...
try to upgrade the **com.android.support:appcompat-v7** like this

```
dependencies {
compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:24.0.0'
compile 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:[4,5)'
}
```

and here is my facebook login button

```
  <com.facebook.login.widget.LoginButton
    android:id="@+id/login_button"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="30dp" />
```

I hope this will help!